# Referring questions to crypto.SE

Tags: discussion, scope

Consider the following two questions:

- [Information leaking of simulation based security](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/8456/information-leaking-of-simulation-based-security)
- [Why SHA-224 and SHA-256 use different initial values?](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/8455/why-sha-224-and-sha-256-use-different-initial-values)

There's already a scope clash between [crypto.SE](http://crypto.stackexchange.com) and us, and I think these questions might be examples of questions that could be referred there ? On the other hand, it's not like we're getting too many questions, and in analogous situations, we don't usually get questions transferred from MO (although cross posting often happens)

Should we be trying to <strike>move</strike> encourage users to crosspost ?

Comment: If you are not sure, why don’t you just suggest the asker to consider posting the question to crypto.stackexchange.com?  As you said, [migrating does not sound like an option](http://meta.cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/1285/to-migrate-or-not-to-migrate-just-close/1292#1292).

Comment: Also the crypto site is in beta and migrating questions to beta sites is unusual. IMO, it is better to leave it to the OP to decide which site is more likely to give an answer of the type she/he is looking for.

Comment: I guess my point is: should we be encouraging posters to cross post there or not.

Comment: Then why don’t you edit your question.  Your question explicitly asks about “moving” the questions over, which is usually taken to mean migration.